# Does only the child element contain text/data in xml

Tags: xml

For example, assume that we have an element "car" which contains child elements like color, wheels etc each with its own text eg: color: red and wheel four. But can "car" itself contain text like BMW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called mixed content e.g.:

```
<root>
  <element>abc<child>xyz</child>def<child>nop</child>hij</element>
</root>
```

is valid xml.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed and XML will be well-formed. Anyway, you should avoid doing so if possible.